# convert "$binary" : "r05rXSs5cUuEFQCujcuW6", "$type" : "03" into a UUID format which is coming form mongo db

Tags: mongodb, groovy, mongodb-query, uuid

Converting  "$binary" : "r05rXSs5cUuEFQCujcuW6g", "$type" : "03" into a UUID format so that i can get a valid value for a single key as String.

I got  "$binary" : "r05rXSs5cUuEFQCujcuW", "$type" : "03" while extracting data from mongoDB

"$binary" : "r05rXSs5cUuEFQCujcuW", "$type" : "03"

i need a single String from binary and type which is stored in MongoDB.

Comment: Type 03 seems to be object https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#behavior how was it stored?

Comment: its Stored in a .NET UUID Legacy format.